# Use Map to store array values and the number of repetitions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to resolve an exercise in which I have to create an array with the letters of my name, and then, using Map, store the values and the number of times that each value appears.

I've been reading about Map and I guess that I should start with something similar to this to check if the array has repetitions, but I'm a newbie and I don't find many Map examples, so I have no idea of what I'm doing…

```js
  var myMap = new Map([[1, "M"], [2, "a"], [3, "r"], [4, "y"]]);

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
console.log(myMap.has (i));
console.log(myMap.get (i));

  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should start with an array of letters. The Map will be used to count accurences.

Comment: Plenty of Map examples here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Not an answer, just a hint that `"Mary".split("")` returns `["M","a","r","y"]`. May or may not be useful in your case :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var nameArray = Array.from("mary")
console.log(nameArray)
var map = new Map()

nameArray.forEach(function(character) {
 if (map.has(character)) {
    map.set(character, map.get(character) + 1)
  } else {
    map.set(character, 1)
  }
});

console.log(map);
```

I've updated your code for your exercise, please refer these docs for Map and Array API:

1. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
2. [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Please comment if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I guess that there're several possible solutions, but this was what I was trying to do and I didn't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Start off with something like this:

```
var myName = ['M', 'a', 'r', 'y'];
var letterFrequencyMap = new Map();

for (var i = 0; i < myName.length; i++) {
    // Your logic to update letterFrequencyMap
}

console.log(letterFrequencyMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with an empty map and ger the count ot a letter with

```
map.get(letters[i])
```

or take zero if a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value is retuned. Then add one and set the the new value.

```js
var string = 'annabelle',
    letters = string.split(''),
    map = new Map,
    i, l;
    
for (i = 0, l = letters.length; i < l; ++i) {
    map.set(letters[i], (map.get(letters[i]) || 0) + 1);
}

map.forEach((v, k) => console.log(k, v));
```

A short version

```js
var string = 'annabelle',
    map = string
        .split('')
        .reduce((map, char) => map.set(char, (map.get(char) || 0) + 1), new Map);
    
map.forEach((v, k) => console.log(k, v));
```

Comment: Thank you, Nina. I was trying to do something a bit different using the has() method, but your solution is also great.